# Como fazer o input seguir o ultimo caractere inserido?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, input

O problema é o seguinte.

Eu fiz uma calculadora e o input de resultado esta como `readonly`. Para inserir o número nela só clicando nos botões que eu fiz como mostra a foto a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao chegar no final do input ele não segue o ultimo caractere pois só faria isso se o input estivesse em foco(ou seja, se eu estivesse digitando nele).

Como eu posso fazer o input sempre seguir o ultimo caractere ?

Segue abaixo meu projeto no **Codepen**.

[Projeto Calculadora no Codepen](https://codepen.io/John_Covv/pen/gEpyaw)

Comment: Sem o seu código só é possível te responder no chute, poste pelo menos um Codepen ou JSFiddle para podermos testar

Comment: Vc teria que concatenar o valor que já tem no input + o número clicado. Mas é bom ver seu código pois há formas diferentes de fazer isso.

Comment: @hugocsl Editei meu post, aquele foi o meu código js que usei para ir acrescentando os números digitados. (Eu sou iniciante, então fiz da forma mais básica, não sei se tem forma melhor).

Comment: John, acredito que seria legal vc colocar o código inteiro, incluindo CSS e HTML além do JS, pois sem o CSS e o HTML não da para simular a sua calculadora. Em **último** vc tb pode postar seu codigo em um  Codepen ou JSFiddle e postar o link aqui.

Comment: @hugocsl Upei no codepen, o link esta no final do post, aceito qualquer correção.

Comment: Cara parece que quando o texto do input é maior que a largura do input acontece um por padrão um alinhar do texto a esquerda no hora do Blur, mesmo o input inicialmente estándo com o alinhamento a direita... Então quando o texto do input ultrapassar a largura dele e vc clicar fora do campo ele não alinha o texto "corretamente".... Veja esse gif https://imgur.com/Qbi3l8D olha o que acontece depois que eu preencho e clico fora, ele coloca o texto no início....

Comment: O alinhamento só fica na direita se o input estiver focado. Estou pesquisando como arrumar isso.

Comment: @hugocsl Pronto, consegui alterar usando o atributo "direction" do css, e adicionei o msm em ":not(:focus)".

Comment: Muito bom John, boa sacada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Vou dar uma dica e uma resposta que pode resolver o seu problema.*

### Todas alinhadas a direita

90% das calculadores que eu conheço o alinhamento do texto é a direita. Sabe por que? Porque conforme o número vai crescendo vc sabe sempre o último algarismo que foi digitado e pode conferir na tela o último número que foi inputado.

Então evite mudar o comportamento padrão de objetos já conhecidos. Vc pode ler sobre **Affordance** aqui https://brasil.uxdesign.cc/affordance-o-%C3%B3bvio-do-%C3%B3bvio-e91761f4403b

> *Affordance* termo inglês, sem tradução atualmente no português, mas que, neste contexto, poderia ser facilmente traduzido por **"reconhecimento"** ou "oportunidade"

*Fonte:* https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance

Então, até por uma questão de eurística, seria interessante manter o alinhamento a direita, que é a forma que a maioria dos usuários estão acostumados e que corresponde com mais fidelidade as calculadores "reais".

Euristicas de Nielsen

- **Segunda Lei:** Correspondência entre o sistema e o mundo real
- **Quarta Lei:** Consistência e padrões

Mais qui: http://blog.caelum.com.br/10-heuristicas-de-nielsen-uma-formula-pra-evitar-erros-basicos-de-usabilidade/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Essa é a calculadora do Google**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Essa é a do Windows**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E essa do Android**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Agora o código que pode te ajudar

Basicamente no seu `input` vc deve colocar um `text-align: right`

```html
<input type="text" style="text-align:right" placeholder="digite aqui">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" style="text-align:right" readonly value="texto a direita 0">
```

Comment: Eu não tinha prestado atenção e nem pensado sobre isso, estava tão focado em fazer aquilo acontecer que nem pensei sobre mudar o alinhamento pra direita. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @JohnCovv sem problemas meu caro! Apesar de ter sido simples pra resolver, tem todo um "por que" de se usar o alinhamento ali. Boa sorte no projeto ai []´s